# Exchange 2007 Replication Plan

Tags: exchange-2007, replication, backup-restoration, data-recovery

At the moment I have 1 exchange 2007 server that I am backing up with backup-exec.  I'm trying to come up with a way to handle something going wrong with him, how can I get back up and running.  What I have thought so far is I would like to have another exchange server here that will replicate every 4 hours or so (is this possible?).  Also I have another datacenter in another state that I would like to have exchange 2007 running at as well that would replicate every 24 hours in the event of a total site loss.  I'm really just looking for a starting point as I'm not by any means a server guy, but I have now been given this hat.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to upgrade to Exchange 2010? A database availability group with replay lag and site resilience would solve all of your problems.

Exchange 2007 has some site resilience stuff built in, but Exchange 2010 is AMAZING at it. Here's a read for you on 2007's options:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201662(EXCHG.80).aspx